# Changing color of already printed text

Tags: beamer, color

For making a small quiz in class I am working on a presentation in `beamer`.

I want to change the color of statements to red (wrong statement) or green (right statement) but only *after* my class answered the question.

I was searching the internet, but only found the `color` package, where you apparently can only change the text color *before* it appears.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) provides an overlay specification with most of its macros/environments. It allows you to say (for example) `...\alert<2>{<stuff>}...` so that `<stuff>` prints normally on slides *other* than number 2. `\color` itself is overlay aware in the form `\color<2->{blue}{<stuff>}` that would print `<stuff>` in blue from slide 2 *onward*. Alternatively, one can use something like `...{\only<2>{\color{blue}}<stuff>}...` which prints `<stuff>` in blue *only* on slide 2.

Here's a short example

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text {\only<2>{\color{blue}}and stuff}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that `beamer` already loads [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor).

Comment: This is exactly what I need, with one little modification: I want the blue stuff be shown after, say, slide 2.

Comment: I found it on the documentation page you linked, I will have to write \only<2-> and so on. Thanks! :)

Comment: `\color` also affects the text after "and stuff", so if you do not want the rest of the line to turn blue, make sure you use `{\color<2->{blue}{and stuff}} and more stuff` instead of  `\color<2->{blue}{and stuff} and more stuff`.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre: Correct. That's what I used. The grouping limits the scope of `\color`. Alternatively, since `\color` is overlay-aware, you can use `{\color<2>{blue}and stuff}`.

Answer (score 5):

I searched for the difinition of `alert` command, and found these:

```
% beamercolorthemedefault.sty
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}
% beamerfontthemedefault.sty
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{}
% beamerbasearticle.sty
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{alerted text begin}{default}{\ifmmode\else\begin{itshape}\fi}
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{alerted text end}{default}{\ifmmode\else\end{itshape}\fi}
% beamerbaselocalstructure.sty
\newenvironment{alertenv}{\begin{altenv}%
    {\usebeamertemplate{alerted text begin}\usebeamercolor[fg]{alerted text}\usebeamerfont{alerted text}}
    {\usebeamertemplate{alerted text end}}{\color{.}}{}}{\end{altenv}}
\newcommand<>{\alert}[1]{\begin{alertenv}#2\relax#1\end{alertenv}}
```

Simillary I define `rightstate` and `wrongstate` commands that can be used like `alert` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{rightstateed text}{fg=green}
\setbeamerfont{rightstateed text}{}
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{rightstateed text begin}{default}{\ifmmode\else\begin{itshape}\fi}
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{rightstateed text end}{default}{\ifmmode\else\end{itshape}\fi}
\newenvironment{rightstateenv}{\begin{altenv}%
    {\usebeamertemplate{rightstateed text begin}\usebeamercolor[fg]{rightstateed text}\usebeamerfont{rightstateed text}}
    {\usebeamertemplate{rightstateed text end}}{\color{.}}{}}{\end{altenv}}
\newcommand<>{\rightstate}[1]{\begin{rightstateenv}#2\relax#1\end{rightstateenv}}

\setbeamercolor{wrongstateed text}{fg=red}
\setbeamerfont{wrongstateed text}{}
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{wrongstateed text begin}{default}{\ifmmode\else\begin{itshape}\fi}
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{wrongstateed text end}{default}{\ifmmode\else\end{itshape}\fi}
\newenvironment{wrongstateenv}{\begin{altenv}%
    {\usebeamertemplate{wrongstateed text begin}\usebeamercolor[fg]{wrongstateed text}\usebeamerfont{wrongstateed text}}
    {\usebeamertemplate{wrongstateed text end}}{\color{.}}{}}{\end{altenv}}
\newcommand<>{\wrongstate}[1]{\begin{wrongstateenv}#2\relax#1\end{wrongstateenv}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \wrongstate<2>{wrong statement}
    \item \rightstate<3>{right statement}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:
[image]