# Colored text flow for demonstrating proof of a theorem

Tags: beamer, color, overlays

I have written a big proof in a frame. I used `\pause` command to uncover the logic step by step.

What I want to do is that in the 1st slide will contain a alerted redtext. 2nd Slide contain the previous sentence with black color and the current sentence is alerted red color. 3rd Slide should contain previous two sentence in black color and the current uncovered sentence in red color. And so on...

What I did is like the following MWE. But I want a color flow to highlight the current sentence content

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

sentence1   \pause

sentence2   \pause

sentence3   \pause

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Also I think you can use thisvery simmiliar question for you answer it [might even be a duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80037/changing-color-of-already-printed-text)

Comment: Try with `\alert<.(1)>{sentence1}   \pause

\alert<.(1)>{sentence2}   \pause

\alert<.(1)>{sentence3}`